# Diagram Splitting

Tags: c#, grid, geometry, diagram

Hi i would like to split my Diagram in four Parts, so i defined 4 equal Rectangle, but in 
bounds3 and bounds4 there still some missing Nodes. can anyone help!

```
//b = (X, Y, Width, Height).
// Original Diagram
Rect b = activeDiagram.Panel.DiagramBounds; // b = (-370, -190, 3099, 2450).

Rect bounds1 = new Rect(b.X, b.Y, w/2, h/2); //top left corner
Rect bounds2 = new Rect(b.X, b.Y + h/2, w/2, h/2); //bottom left corner
Rect bounds3 = new Rect(b.X + w/2, b.Y, w/2, h/2); //top right corner 
Rect bounds4 = new Rect(b.X + w/2, b.Y + h/2, w/2, h/2); //bottom right corner
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can loose one-point wide strips with integer division (3099 div 2 + 3099 div 2 = 3098)

Use width = w - w/2 for right column and height = h - h/2 for bottom row to cover all the initial rectangle.

Comment: it dosnt make any difference its the same solution for Width = w/2 and Height = h/2

Comment: I don't know in details, how these expressions are evaluated in C# (may be, some kind of float-integer conversion?).